# /odometry/filtered output arrow not showing in rviz

Tags: ros2, odometry, robot-localization, ros-humble, sensor-fusion

I am using a VM Box to work on sensor fusion for turtlebot3 on ROS2-Humble. When i  run my turltebot launch file and ekf launch file..it runs...and when I launch rviz to visualize the arrows from both /odom and /odometry_filtered topics, only arrow from odom topic comes. but /odometry_filtered arrow is not visible even though the messages are correctly being published on the topic.

I have verified the rqt_tf_tree, frames and all of them seems fine. Can anyone hep me out. below are the images - tf_tree[image: output from both the topics in rviz]

Comment: can you change the frame_id for /odometry_filtered to odom or something else in rviz and check?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue, by setting 'use_sim_true' to True in the ekf.launch.py file -

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import launch_ros.actions
import os
import yaml
from launch.substitutions import EnvironmentVariable
import pathlib
import launch.actions
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_localization',
            executable='ekf_node',
            name='ekf_filter_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("robot_localization"), 'params', 'ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': True}]
           ),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider you are running in a sim, it is quite possible that both of these poses are overlapping, try turning off the `/odom` topic visualization and then check. You can also try changing the size of pose arrow by changing `shaft radius` and `shaft length` values for both.

Comment: I fixed it by setting use_sim_time to true inside the ekf_launch file. Thanks tho